# How to setup 2 web apps on http

Tags: http, web, flask, https

I have two web services running on my sample.com domain, one on port 80 and the other on port 3030. Both work on http. When I just connect to http://sample.com/, the page loads fine, but when http://sample.com:3030/ gives a ssl certificate error, and even if I manually write the http in the address bar, it still redirects to the https. How to fix? Apache or ngnix web server is not worth it, only 2 flask apps. I just want to connect via http to my web service 3030.

---

I've heard a lot of advice about clearing .htaccess cache, it didn't help me, problem still exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from either a browser extension e.g. [HTTPS everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) or due to an option enabled by a cdn like cloudflare to redirect your traffic.

The Certificate Error is raised by the borwser because your application reacts with http instead of https and doesn't provide the appropriate response.

To mitigate this problem use a webserver and a appropriate deployment to provide https. Otherwise if you really need http run in locally. A web server is *mandatory* for any application that's exposed to the public. The flask development server is not for *production*.